# facebook native adview replace original item of the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am trying implement facebook native ad on recyclerview..

one adview on 1st position than after every 14 position.

adview is implemented successfully but problem is adview is replace the original item of the recyclerView..

i try searching in SO but not found better solution.
i also try add null value in ad position but that is also not work correctly..   '

here is my code

playAdapter.java

```
public class PlayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  private static final String TAG = "playadapter";

  private ArrayList<TempModel> nameArraylist = new ArrayList<>();
  private static Context context;
  private static boolean isClicked = true;

  // for click with interface
  private static OnItemClickListener mListener;
  private int lastCheckedPos = 0;
  private int row_index;

  //
  public int SINGLE_AD_TYPE = 0;
  public int DEFAULT_CONTENT = 1;
  public int SECOND_AD_TYPE = 2;


  public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
  }

  public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
  }



  public PlayAdapter(ArrayList<TempModel> nameArraylist, Context context) {
    this.nameArraylist = nameArraylist;
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 1) {
      return SINGLE_AD_TYPE;
    } else if (position != 0 && position % 13 == 0) {

      return SECOND_AD_TYPE;
    } else {
      return DEFAULT_CONTENT;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == SINGLE_AD_TYPE) {

      View adLayoutOutline =
          LayoutInflater.from(context)
              .inflate(R.layout.item_facebook_native_ad_outline, parent, false);
      ViewGroup vg = adLayoutOutline.findViewById(R.id.ad_container);

      LinearLayout adLayoutContent =
          (LinearLayout)
              LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                  .inflate(R.layout.item_facebook_native_ad, parent, false);
      vg.addView(adLayoutContent);
      return new SingleAdViewHolder(adLayoutOutline);
              return new SingleAdViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == SECOND_AD_TYPE) {
      View adLayoutOutline =
          LayoutInflater.from(context)
              .inflate(R.layout.item_facebook_native_ad_outline, parent, false);
      ViewGroup vg = adLayoutOutline.findViewById(R.id.ad_container);

      LinearLayout adLayoutContent =
          (LinearLayout)
              LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                  .inflate(R.layout.item_facebook_native_ad, parent, false);
      vg.addView(adLayoutContent);
      return new SecondAdViewHolder(adLayoutOutline);
    } else {
      View view =
          LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.play_row_item, parent, false);

      return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    if (holder instanceof SingleAdViewHolder) {
      onBindAdViewHolder(holder);

    } else if (holder instanceof SecondAdViewHolder) {
      final SecondAdViewHolder singleAdViewHolder = (SecondAdViewHolder) holder;
      final NativeAd nativeAd =
          new NativeAd(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.fb_banner_ad));
      nativeAd.setAdListener(
          new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
              Log.d(TAG, "onError: " + adError.getErrorMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
              Toast.makeText(context, "" + nativeAd.getAdTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdTitle());

              singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
              singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBody());
              singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdCallToAction.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());

              NativeAd.Image adIcon = nativeAd.getAdIcon();
              NativeAd.downloadAndDisplayImage(adIcon, singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdIcon);

              singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdMedia.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

              AdChoicesView adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(context, nativeAd, true);
              singleAdViewHolder.adChoicesContainer.removeAllViews();
              singleAdViewHolder.adChoicesContainer.addView(adChoicesView);

              List<View> clickableViews = new ArrayList<>();
              clickableViews.add(singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdTitle);
              clickableViews.add(singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdCallToAction);
              nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(
                  singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdContainer, clickableViews);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {}

            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {}
          });
      nativeAd.loadAd();
    } else {
      MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
      myViewHolder.textView.setText(nameArraylist.get(position).getName());
      Picasso.get().load(nameArraylist.get(position).getImage()).into(myViewHolder.imageView);

      if (row_index == position) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams =
            (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) myViewHolder.cardView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParamsCard =
            (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) myViewHolder.mCv_round_img.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParamsCard.setMargins(19, 0, 0, 0);
        myViewHolder.cardView.setRadius(0);
        myViewHolder.mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myViewHolder.cardView.requestLayout();
        myViewHolder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#393939"));
        myViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected);
        myViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#393939"));
        myViewHolder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
      } else {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams =
            (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) myViewHolder.cardView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(15, 10, 15, 10);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParamsCard =
            (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) myViewHolder.mCv_round_img.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParamsCard.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        // holder.cardView.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        myViewHolder.mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        myViewHolder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
      }
      myViewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(
          new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              if (mListener != null) {
                row_index = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                int positionn = position;
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + position);
                mListener.onItemClick(positionn);
              }
            }
          });
    }
  }

  private void onBindAdViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    final SingleAdViewHolder singleAdViewHolder = (SingleAdViewHolder) holder;
    final NativeAd nativeAd =
        new NativeAd(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.fb_banner_ad));
    nativeAd.setAdListener(
        new AdListener() {
          @Override
          public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError: " + adError.getErrorMessage());
          }

          @Override
          public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + nativeAd.getAdTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdTitle());

            singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
            singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBody());
            singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdCallToAction.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());

            NativeAd.Image adIcon = nativeAd.getAdIcon();
            NativeAd.downloadAndDisplayImage(adIcon, singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdIcon);

            singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdMedia.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

            AdChoicesView adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(context, nativeAd, true);
            singleAdViewHolder.adChoicesContainer.removeAllViews();
            singleAdViewHolder.adChoicesContainer.addView(adChoicesView);

            List<View> clickableViews = new ArrayList<>();
            clickableViews.add(singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdTitle);
            clickableViews.add(singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdCallToAction);
            nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(
                singleAdViewHolder.nativeAdContainer, clickableViews);
          }

          @Override
          public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {}

          @Override
          public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {}
        });
    nativeAd.loadAd();
  }


  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return nameArraylist.size();
  }

  public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private static final String TAG = "holder";
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    CardView cardView, mCv_round_img;
    View mView;
    int firstposition;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ply_row_text);
      imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playcv_img);
      mView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_rv_play);
      cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_play_cv);
      mCv_round_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_round_play);
    }
  }

  private static class SingleAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView nativeAdIcon;
    TextView nativeAdTitle;
    MediaView nativeAdMedia;
    TextView nativeAdSocialContext;
    TextView nativeAdBody;
    Button nativeAdCallToAction;
    LinearLayout adChoicesContainer;
    LinearLayout nativeAdContainer;
    boolean loaded;

    public SingleAdViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      nativeAdContainer = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fb_native_ad_container);
      nativeAdIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_icon);
      nativeAdTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_title);
      nativeAdMedia = (MediaView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_media);
      nativeAdSocialContext = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_social_context);
      nativeAdBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_body);
      nativeAdCallToAction = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_call_to_action);
      adChoicesContainer = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_choices_container);
    }
  }

  private static class SecondAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView nativeAdIcon;
    TextView nativeAdTitle;
    MediaView nativeAdMedia;
    TextView nativeAdSocialContext;
    TextView nativeAdBody;
    Button nativeAdCallToAction;
    LinearLayout adChoicesContainer;
    LinearLayout nativeAdContainer;
    boolean loaded;

    public SecondAdViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      nativeAdContainer = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fb_native_ad_container);
      nativeAdIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_icon);
      nativeAdTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_title);
      nativeAdMedia = (MediaView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_media);
      nativeAdSocialContext = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_social_context);
      nativeAdBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_body);
      nativeAdCallToAction = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_call_to_action);
      adChoicesContainer = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_choices_container);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you loop through your list before providing it to `adapter` and add on desired position `null` than replace `null` by add inside adapter, it will work.

Comment: thanks for answer..but i also tried that..

Comment: Still doesn't mean that will not work

Comment: thats worked but when i used that list (next and prevoius) return null at the ad position..
sorry for bad english

Comment: Then add empty item like placeholder instead of adding `null`

Comment: thanks....
 but can you show some code snippet or example?